# NSProgressIndicator with clear background

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

Can't get NSProgressIndicator to have clear background, it shows with gray background regardless:

```
let progressbar = NSProgressIndicator.init(frame: NSRect(x: 10, y: y+4, width: 60, height: 60))
progressbar.style = NSProgressIndicatorStyle.SpinningStyle
progressbar.controlTint = NSControlTint.ClearControlTint
progressbar.wantsLayer = true
progressbar.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor().CGColor
self.contentView.addSubview(progressbar)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is like 3 years late, and I know you might've already ready got it but here's the answer.

```
progressbar.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearance.Name.aqua)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to set wantsLayer = true to window itself (and perhaps to the content view).

Comment: I've never seen a need to have: progressbar.controlTint = NSControlTint.ClearControlTint
progressbar.wantsLayer = true
progressbar.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor().CGColor . When you use IB you just drop the guy on a surface of desired control and it has transparent back. Sometimes there are issues with CI layers then you set parent to have layer. Sorry I could not help...